# Where can I find documentation on the pyparsing module?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am working through some code to integrate Anaconda environments with ArcGIS. The tutorial I'm following makes use of the pyparsing module. I'd like to better understand the module but am having difficulty finding a good overview of the commands within it. Where can I find documentation for the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be on github.  I found it here: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!